# "eth_requestAccounts" but without causing MetaMask to pop up

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, browsers

This function call

```
  const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'})
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e.message);
      return;
    });
```

will actively prompt the user to connect his MetaMask wallet **if he has not done yet.**

How could I **check** whether or not it's connected? Meaning, I don't want MetaMask to pop up if a user hasn't been connected yet. I only want to check the status of connection.